# In an iOS table view, how should a row be moved to a new section?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with two rows in one section, i.e

```
---
Row A
Row B
```

If I want to animate row 1 into a new section, i.e. the end result being:

```
---
Row B
---
Row A
```

how should this be achieved?  What I have tried already is:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: 0 inSection: 0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

However, in iOS 8 at least, the row animates out but then the new section is un-rendered (i.e. white, no bottom row border) until some time after when something triggers a redraw and it comes back.

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Which raises an exception:

```
Invalid update: invalid number of sections. The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).
```

And:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Which raises the exception:

```
cannot move a row into a newly inserted section (1)
```

Should I just not animate at all and reload the whole table?

Comment: Maybe better to separate the Data Layer with the View Layer. I.e. Load your data with designed data source, maybe 2-D array, then modify the array and call tableView.reload

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to perform this in two steps.

First you'll need to add the section; you need to tell your data source to account for the new section. For a simple example like yours, you can just set a variable:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if(hasTwoSections)
        return 2;

    return 1;
}
```

Then where you want to trigger the animation, call:

```
hasTwoSections = true;  // this needs to be set before endUpdates
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex: 1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

At this point, the tableView will call the data source methods to update the table based on your changes.

Once the section has been added, you can move the row to it in another update block:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Obviously you'll need to update what numberOfRowsInSection returns to account for the change.

Although it's two steps, it will look like it's happening all at once.

Comment: If you're only doing one operation, I don't think the beginUpdates and endUpdates are necessary.

Comment: That's true, the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls aren't necessary in this example.

Comment: @Bruce Geerdes, false, if you're moving you do need to call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` - [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614987-moverow)

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation where I was getting the exception `cannot move a row into a newly inserted section (1)`. I only found two ***half*** solutions.

1. Reload the table with `reloadData()` - aggressive, and no animations
2. Delete and insert your rows, code below:

---

```
self.requestTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([oldIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
self.requestTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
```

To get animations effects that give the impression of the rows moving, you could use `UITableViewRowAnimation.Top` when deleting, inserting, or reloading sections.

```
self.tableView.deleteSections(toDelete, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
self.tableView.insertSections(toInsert, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
self.tableView.reloadSections(toReload, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`-[UITableView moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitableview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:)

Comment: I tried that.  I also tried inserting the section then moving the row.  Both produce exceptions.

Comment: If you just do move, you get:

     Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).

Comment: If you insert the section then move, you get: cannot move a row into a newly inserted section (1)

Comment: You must make sure that at the point you call `endUpdates` the methods `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` must correctly reflect the new values.

Comment: Yes, those methods return the correct values.  The error message states the problem is the sections have not been inserted or deleted.  If I insert them, it has already loaded the row.  The problem is, because the new row is the same object as the row that has been removed from another section, it fails to render it correctly.  I think the only solution to this would be a table reload.

Comment: Ah I see your new problem. You could always use two sections even if section 1 is empty at first. Then you can just animate the row into the empty section since you don't need to create it anymore.

Comment: You can return nil for `headerForSection` to control that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62878/discussion-between-nick-and-fluidsonic).